# Como efetuar um upload em um site FTP?

Tags: delphi, upload, ftp, object-pascal

Olá, tenho uma conta FTP em um domínio, ela é protegida por senha porém eu necessito que uma aplicação do Delphi faça upload de arquivos ao invés do FileZila e outros. Como poderei fazer uploads de arquivos? Tentei de acordo com alguns sites e em nenhum deles eu obtive sucesso, vocês podem conferir a lista abaixo. Peço que poste respostas de eficacia comprovada.

http://balaiotecnologico.blogspot.com.br/2010/10/fazendo-download-e-upload-usando-ftp.html

http://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/transferindo-arquivos-via-ftp-pelo-delphi/433855

Comment: Como esta seu código com os links que você utilizou? Qual o erro que retornava?

Comment: Valeu! Eu já corrigi o problema aki!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adicione o componente `TIdFTP` e utilize o comando abaixo:

```
IdFTP1.Host := 'IP do host FTP';

IdFTP1.username := 'Usuário do host FTP';

IdFTP1.password := 'Senha do host FTP';

IdFTP1.connect; {conecta e se loga}

IdFTP1.Put('Arquivo de envio');
```